Why is Pycharm's warning system not working
I altered the settings of Pycharm so as to tone down the number of warnings, but now no warnings appear at all and I can't remember what parameter I put in so as to get things back to the way they were. I've tried restarting Pycharm, even downloading the latest version but the problem persists. For the latest version I also tried resetting Pycharm to the factory settings and although this did return some things to normal, it did not return everything to normal since I still had breakpoints from an old Pycharm version.  This is what my inspection configurations look like (I'm using a Mac):

This is what my pycharm looks like:

As you can see b = 0 should be greyed out as unused and d.add should have a red line underneath since it is an error, same goes for c=1/0.  When I look at the problems window I get a very long list of errors as seen here:

When you zoom out, there should a slew of red marks on the right column window but there are none:

I went back and looked at an old Pycharm which I should have thrown away but luckily I did not.  This is what Pycharm used to look like and should look line now but does not.  As you can see b = c/2 is both greyed out and there is a red line under c which is what I want:

Looking at the old inspection setting one finds

The setting options have changed for the new version so I cannot recreate them in the latest version. Any help would be appreciated.  If I can spot errors before running the code I can save myself heaps of time. So it's very important that I get this resolved.

There's a dropdown box that when you press it, it gives you the option of suppressing warnings.  It's located here:

